# Imread in a loop: How to write the image name?

Tags: image, matlab, for-loop, imread

I implemented a loop where I read images from a folder and do some calculation on each of these. I then write the result in a txt file.
I'm starting to think that it doesn't read the images in the right order (the names are following each others: XYZ_1.bmp, XYZ_2.bmp 3-4-5-6...) because when I do the calculation on only one image, I get the result of another image.

Therefore, I would like to write the name of the image on my result txt file in order to check if it is the right image.

I did not succeed.
I'm guessing the code I made is not saving the image name when reading it, isn't it ? Do you have tips ? 
Is that anyway possible that the code is not reading the image in the right order (1-2-3-4...) ?

Here is my code :

```
rep=sprintf('foldername');
ext='*.bmp';
chemin = fullfile(rep,ext);
list1 = dir(chemin);
n=numel(list1);

A=zeros(4,n); % result tab

for k=1:n 
I= imread(fullfile(rep,list1(k).name),ext(3:end));
%SOME CALCULATIONS


%Filling up result tab
    A(1,k)=ME;
    A(2,k)=NU;
    A(3,k)=PO;
    A(4,k)=N;
end

fid = fopen('Parameters_Seg_Im5_9.txt','w');
fprintf(fid,'%5s %5s %4s %6s\r\n','ME', 'NU', 'P', 'N');
fprintf(fid,'%5.4f %5.4f %4.3f %7d\r\n',A);
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: your code seems incomplete as there are 2 `end` but only 1 `for`. Please provide a working example that reproduces the problem. Also where is the call to `imread`?

Comment: Indeed, sorry, I rewrited the code. There is not need of the calculation code, it will only overload the question... The key point is in the loop imread : is it possible to extract the image name ? Thanks

Comment: Minor note.  The second parameter to `imread` isn't required.  `imread` will infer this from the filename itself.  You only specify the second parameter if it is not obvious from the filename what the image format is.

Comment: You can put in a couple of debug statements at the beginning of your loop to show the name and the parameters for each image... something like:  `fprintf('Filename: %s\n', fullfile(rep,list1(k).name)); disp('Parameters'); disp(A(:,k));`  This will show you each filename and the parameters of each filename at each iteration.

Comment: Perfect @raryreng, I now know that it doesn't read the images in the right order! It is read :1;10;11;12;13;14;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9. So I know how to correct it. Are there rules about the name_writing in matlab ?         About the 2nd parameter `imread`, I use it in case there is something else in the folder (not a `.bmp`that I want to use).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I wrote filenames was not right :1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11...

I guess the rule is to write filenames **with the maximum number of digits** : 001-002-003-004...-...-100...-...-999.

Question solved: writing tips!